# ArrayAdapter:you must supply a resource id for a textview

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-arrayadapter

i have an app in which i want to fill the ListView by data from SQLite Database...in this part i have an problem, with arrayAdapter...

here is my code of the method for fill the listView:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);
    PetListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);


    MyDatabaseHelper db = new MyDatabaseHelper(this);
    String [] items = new String[100];


    List<Pet> pets = db.getAllPets();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        items[i] = pets.get(i).getName();                   
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.activity_list_item, R.id.textView1list, items);
    PetListView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

and this is method implemented in my database helper:

```
public List<Pet> getAllPets() {
    List<Pet> petList = new ArrayList<Pet>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_PETS;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Pet pet = new Pet();
            pet.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            pet.setName(cursor.getString(1));
            pet.setAge(cursor.getString(2));
            petList.add(pet);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    return petList;     
}
```

Why textView? I'm only using ListView...

Can you anybody tell me any other way how to fill the listView by data(names) from SQLite?

Comment: TextView is one of the many possible ways to display your data. Each item in your list view needs to be shown in some way. Using `TextView` shows it as text.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

use

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
          android.R.layout.activity_list_item, android.R.id.text1, items);
```

instad of

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
            android.R.layout.activity_list_item, R.id.textView1list, items);
```

use `android.R.id.text1` as TextView id if you are using default `activity_list_item` layout for ListView

Comment: i tried this, but it throws other exception ArrayAdapter: NullpointerException

Comment: of course you will get NullpointerException because you are passing Array of size 100 but you are adding only 10 elements to items array

Comment: @andrew : still getting any issue?